# Last actionbar tab partly obscured or not shown onscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'm using the navigation tabs mode in an actionbar. The tabs are created dynamically along with the fragments which fill them.

My problem is shown in the screenshot below. The more tabs I have in the actionbar the more the last tab becomes obscured/covered. The last tab should read 10030. The tabs start at 10000, so there are only 30 of them. If there are only 10 tabs the view seems okay. At 20 the last character becomes covered, at 100 tabs the entire last tab plus some of the 99th is covered.

This is a `FragmentActivity` using a `ViewPager` and `PagerAdapter`. This is done using the native actionbar not `ActionBarSherlock`. I'm using a split actionbar also.

Has anyone else ever had this issue? Or anything similar?

[image: screenshot]

This is running on a HTC One X on 4.0.3. I have replicated this issue on another phone (Huawei G300 Ascend) running 4.0.4. I have searched and found nothing related to this issue on this or any other site.

Comment: Hmm interesting, might be a bug that has gone unnoticed since its not common habbit to add 30 tabs.. or mostly even more then 3-4

Comment: I know it's probably not common to see this many tabs. Chances are I won't ever have this many tabs in a normal use case but it is possible (due to the underlying logic) that's why I was generating relatively high numbers of the underlying data. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yeah sorry can't really give any fix. I guess your best bet is to post this as bug on the google forum and see if someone from google can give you actual advise and maybe even put it on the to-do list.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean Google Groups or the google section on this site.